# Fast way to see which pipeline use what datasets in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working in Azure data factory, where i have many pipelines and a lot of data sets as well. Does any one know if there is a fast way to see which datsets are used which activities in certain pipelines?

Sincerely
Christian

Comment: you can use Rest API

Comment: https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/12/18/automated-way-to-identify-the-dependencies-on-a-dataset-in-an-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dataset, go to Properties, and switch to the "Related" view:

[image]